# Azure Face Recognition - returning 403

Tags: javascript, html, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use Azure Face Recognition but I'm receiving a 403 return. I searched and it looks like a need to fill a form and be approved to use this resource. The problem is that I'm trying to find a solution to use face recognition in my local webpage and if work well I will develop a webpage in production, so I don't have a commercial e-mail or a production url to fill the form.

There is a alternative solution?

To exemplify here is my code and the returning error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Reconhecimento Facial - Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Reconhecimento Facial - Login</h1>

  <div id="message"></div>

  <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

  <button id="loginButton">Login</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Azure Face API Endpoint e Chave de Assinatura
    const endpoint = 'my endpoint';
    const subscriptionKey = 'my key';

    // Elementos de vídeo e canvas
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Função para carregar o vídeo
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || navigator.getUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, stream => {
        video.srcObject = stream;
      }, error => {
        console.log('Erro ao acessar a câmera: ' + error);
      });
    }

    // Função para tirar uma foto e enviar para o Azure Face API para reconhecimento
    function takeSnapshot() {
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

      // Enviar a imagem para o Azure Face API
      axios.post(`${endpoint}/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceAttributes=emotion`, {
        url: imageData
      }, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey
        }
      }).then(response => {
        const faceId = response.data[0].faceId;
        const emotions = response.data[0].faceAttributes.emotion;

        // Verificar as emoções para autenticar o usuário
        if (emotions.happiness > 0.5) {
          // Emoção de felicidade detectada, autenticação bem-sucedida
          showMessage('Usuário autenticado com sucesso!');
        } else {
          // Emoção de felicidade não detectada, autenticação falhou
          showMessage('Falha na autenticação. Por favor, tente novamente.');
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Erro na requisição para o Azure Face API: ' + error);
        showMessage('Erro na requisição para o Azure Face API. Por favor, tente novamente.');
      });
    }

    // Função para exibir mensagens na tela
    function showMessage(message) {
      const messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');
      messageDiv.innerHTML = message;
    }

    // Evento para acionar o reconhecimento facial ao pressionar o botão de login
    const loginButton = document.getElementById('loginButton');
    loginButton.addEventListener('click', takeSnapshot);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Azure & Microsoft are a .... This was not notified to the IT teams, so now we have a lot of users raising tickets and a lot of problems to our companies. We will change to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Face API return 403 error

The above error occurs when you were not authorized to use the capability you were attempting to call from the request, which has now blocked access for them.

Access to the Face service is restricted based on eligibility and use requirements to limit our Responsible AI tenets. To understand the rate limitations and modify the way you use it, see the Face API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/computer-vision/limited-access-identity).

Make sure with proper authentication and you can use the same code and in my environment, it worked successfully.

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services Face API error 403 - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187089/microsoft-azure-cognitive-services-face-api-error?page=1) - romungi-MSFT

[Face API return 403 error - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/908688/face-api-return-403-error?orderBy=Oldest) - YutongTie-MSFT